# Windows 10 and Windows 11 (different ISO) corrupted network settings

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, vpn

This problem is going to sound weird as hell, but bear with me.
I got this new PC last week: AMD Ryzen 7800X3D / 32GB DDR5 7200 Mhz T-Force ram / MSI B650-VC / 1000 watt EVGA PSU / Radeon XFX 7800 XT / Adata Gold 800 2TB ram.

It came originally with Windows 11 and everything at first glance worked fine there. But I installed W10 and this is where problems begin. Everything-everything worked fine except one thing: I use app called Netch to access my VMESS VPN server (I believe it called v2ray protocol or something like that). The reason I use this specific VPN is because my friend is from China and he sells VPNs and this is VPN protocol they are using there. So he just shared one server with me. It was really good VPN, it was reaching 800 mbit/s download speed so it was important for me to have it.
So when I did full fresh install of Windows 10 (I used Rufus and USB stick) I realized that Netch no longer able to connect to VPN server properly. Connection is established but I get error saying: "NO:HTTP, NO:UDP". So basically I could only open Websites that support ipV6 like Google. If website is only IPv4 it just gives timeout error and never opens.

What I tried so far:

1. Resetting Windows Network Settings
2. Reinstalling LAN / Wi-FI drivers + making sure they are recent
3. Updating and Resetting Windows

At the same time when I had issues, I use the same Netch program with my VPN server and I was able to connect on Iphone (using Shadowrocket app) and on different PC using the same Netch program. Everything worked fine.

I decided to download older version of W10 - W10 LTSC 2021. It did help and everything worked but I didn't wanted to use it, so I downloaded fresh copy of W11 from Microsoft website and installed it and Netch was broken again.

I had my friend network engineer to remotely look at my PC and he wasn't been able to find anything wrong but he made conclusion:

1. It's not ports
2. It's not firewall

We also tried to do "scan now" and it did restore some corrupted stuff but none of them affected my problem as it was still there.

My SSD Health shows 100% and no SMART errors in Crystal Disk Mark.
Only problem I had with PC that DDR5 RAM was unstable at 7200mh A-XMP profile. But this instability was only shown in MemTest5 program. I never had BSOD, crash, reboot or any sort of behavior like that.

I dont understand what is going on. I've been using Netch for 2 years on different PCs and I  never had issues. At the same time on the PC where Netch is having issues, I can connect to regular VPN (I used free Windscribe as a test) and it was working fine.

I'm also connected not via LAN cable but via WI-FI and I have Comcast XFinity if its matters.Please give me some suggestions or stuff to try to possible fix it. I can't keep reinstalling Windows in hope that it will randomly work.

Comment: You have a router or ISP device?  Most likely.  Update its firmware and restart it. Test again

Comment: Why not stay with Windows 11 if Netch works in it ? Some new computers do not work well with Windows 10. Which computer model is it?